# Why is my array returned by a method not printing to console?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am writing a program that reads a .txt file into a String array suing a method. However, when I try to test my method by printing the array in the main program, nothing happens. I created a method to read the txt file into an array, and now I am trying to print this array in the main program to make sure it is working correctly.

All help is appreciated, here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class P4Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        
        
        
        // have user enter name for file
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the file");
                String nameOfFile = input.nextLine();
                
                
                String[] test = readFile(nameOfFile);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test));
    }

    
    public static String[] readFile(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        
        
        
        //read the file 
    
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        
        // read number of lines inside file
        
        int numString = 0;
        while (file.hasNextLine());
        {
            ++numString;
            file.nextLine();
        }
        file.close();
        
        // now we read the file into a string array
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    String[] words = new String[numString];
    
    // using a for loop to read in each line to the array
    
    for (int index = 0; index < numString; ++index) {
        words[index] = keyboard.nextLine();
    }
    keyboard.close();
    return words;
    
    
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged the code and are sure the array is not empty?

Comment: @genius42 well if the array is empty that means my code does not work? In which case I would like someone to help me understand why that is.

Comment: It is another issue then. Because nothing will be printed to the console if the array is empty. Try to debug and check the variable values during runtime.

Comment: Add Print statement before " words[index] = keyboard.nextLine();" this line. Is there any content in your file?

Comment: @oxy_js  Okay i did what you said, and it prints out the number of words inside the txt file all the way up to 7699 which is correct. However when i try to print the array containing each word to the console, nothing is displayed. Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine, except for this line:

```
while (file.hasNextLine());
```

You need to remove that semicolon from while loop.

Comment: Wow, I readed the code 3 times and I didn't figured out.

Comment: thank you for the answer! I edited this message as I have now got the program to work thanks to your help!

Comment: I just removed the semicolon and executed your  code, it displayed the file content for me

Comment: check the file location if it is stored in correct place